# In SWTOR is there somewhere that the chat/messages log is stored locally?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I could like to do some analysis on damage as well as keep a record of some of the chats that go on in SWTOR.

You can scroll back when you are in a gaming session, but I would like to look at that log outside of the game itself.

Is that log stored as text somewhere on your machine?  I've not been able to locate so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question should be revisited, because as of patch 1.2, a combat log can be enabled, which writes combat data to text files on your computer.

First, the logging must be enabled from Preferences > Combat Logging > Enable Combat Logging to File.  You do not get to choose a location for the file, instead, the logs are sent to your "My Documents" folder in the "Star Wars - The Old Republic\CombatLogs" subfolder (same place as the Screenshots folder).
[image: combat logging]

Word of warning: the logs are full of *much* more information than you might be used to seeing in a combat log.  For example, here is a single heal on myself:

```
[12:41:45.387] [@Nathrakh] [@Nathrakh] [Benevolence {812710891618304}] [Event {836045448945472}: AbilityActivate {836045448945479}] ()
[12:41:47.009] [@Nathrakh] [@Nathrakh] [] [Spend {836045448945473}: Force {836045448938502}] (45)
[12:41:47.016] [@Nathrakh] [@Nathrakh] [Benevolence {812710891618304}] [ApplyEffect {836045448945477}: Heal {836045448945500}] (1252)
```

Not only can you see the final result (a heal for 1252 HP) but the "AbilityActivate" event and the even a "Spend Force" (45) event.
Because of all this extra information, a log parser is recommended.  There are several online log parser options, such as:
http://swtor.wildking.net/ and http://swtor.askmrrobot.com/combatlog (I am not affiliated with either of these sites).

Answer (score -1):

There is no combat log, but there is a conversation log.  In the chat window, there is an 'other' tab that has your conversation history (at least with NPC's).

Comment: Is that log available outside of the game? I can't find it in any of the obvious locations under my Windows profile or programdata, etc?